# Limit flash cross-domain access to specific locations on server

Tags: flash, cross-domain

Flash cross-domain policy files only allow you to specify *allow-domain-from* tags.
I'd like to know if there is a way to limit access as if the tag read *allow-domain-to*. In other words:

I want my server to be accessible from anywhere, but only if they are trying to request http://example.com/safeaccess.php . All request sent to any other path on my server should be restricted, so can't read http://example.com/somebigfile.php or http://example.com/takesminutetoprocess.php

Is it possible to achieve this without resorting to creating a special sub domain for flash callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some answers on the internet:

http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index.cfm?entry=A094C1CA-FCA1-666F-1F19FECA73FB2C1D

http://blancer.com/tutorials/30030/quick-tip-a-guide-to-cross-domain-policy-files/

Basically you need to have a cross domain policy in the root and in the directory you want to access. The root one should read:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And you also need to add the subdirectory's policy file using:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://example.com/expledirecotyr/crossdomain.xml")
```

Afterwards it should work smoothly.